# How to handle states and transitions in nestjs?

Tags: node.js, express, nestjs, state, transition

what is the best way for handling states and transitions in nestjs

imagine in my app in user registration. when user registered the state will store as created. I have two steps created and started and I have a one transition that is start so that with this transition user state will change from created to started.